# Angular Js template using Xampp

Tags: angularjs, xampp

I have downloaded an angularjs template from GIT and followed the guidelines in the link https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/. Could someone explain the concept behind this and is there any possibility to run the same file using Xampp or Wampp? If not what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Download blur template from [here](http://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/091-downloads/) and access `release` folder from Xampp or Wampp.